# Re-rerender/refresh 3D Object once texture is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I am using three.js to render a 3D box in my Website. This is achieved via the Collada loader as I am loading a .dae file. **Important:** I am using AngularJS so my box scene is loaded in a view and supported by Controllers. For this reason I am also tagging this post as Angular, in case there is a view refresh or controller update issue.

The dae file has references to its texture files.

Example:

```
<library_images>
<image id="Texture_0_png">
<init_from>./Texture_0.png</init_from>
</image>
```

Since I have the texture files in the same Web directory as the Collada file (.dae), it loads as intended. However, I am changing and overwriting the texture files on the fly and need this to be reflected in the 3D model. If I delete the temporary files in my browser manually, it shows the updated texture, but I can't have users manually clearing their cache every time the texture is changed. Since I am retrieving the files over a REST Web service, is there a way to re-render the 3D Object with the new texture, or somehow control the caching so when a texture is overwritten it is displayed in the 3D object without users manually clearing their browser cache?

**Update:** Per Falk Thiele's assistance I have the following, but it requires a page refresh to show changes, where I need it without a page refresh. I am wondering if given the change on refresh, if there is some sort of cache clearing that can occur/is needed...

Here is my current three.js code:

```
    // 3D OBJECT - Variables
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var renderer;
    var box;
    var controls;

    // 3D OBJECT - Generate

    function generate3D() {
        //Instantiate a Collada loader
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        loader.load('https://mywebservicestorage.net/blob1/dae.dae', function (collada) {

            box = collada.scene;

            box.traverse(function (child) {

                if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

                    var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                    animation.play();

                }
            });

            box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
            box.updateMatrix();

            init();
            animate();
        });

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

            renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
            //renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setSize(500, 500);

            // Load the box file
            scene.add(box);

            // Lighting
            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
            scene.add(light);

            // Camera
            camera.position.x = 40;
            camera.position.y = 40;
            camera.position.z = 40;

            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // Rotation Controls
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 5;

            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;

            $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    }

    // Initial 3D Load
    generate3D();
```

Here is my code to refresh the texture once changed (note that this requires a page refresh):

```
$scope.refresh3D = function () {
            box.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://mywebservicestorage.net/Texture_0.png");
        };
```

If I add the following, I get an error of: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined

```
box.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

**Update 2:** The more I investigate this issue, including trying box.needsUpdate = true; in multiple locations, the more it looks like a caching issue. How can I get three.js to see the textures on the server that the Collada file is referencing instead of the cache? Isn't needsUpdate supposed to do this, or is this not a part of the Collada loader.

Comment: Try telling three.js to reload the texture after you replaced it: ```model.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "./Texture_0.png" );```

Comment: That almost works, Using this I still need to refresh the page to make it display, but its better than having to manually clear out the cache. Anyway to have it so the page doesn't refresh, but just the object?

Comment: ```model.material.needsUpdate=true;``` and rerender in case you arent already.

Comment: I am newer to three.js and have not rerendered before. Is there a separate call for that, or would I just wrap all my threejs code in a function and run that function to rerender? I am adding my current code to my original post.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear; in case you are not continously rendering with requestAnimationFrame, give the ```renderer.render( camera, scene );``` a call after setting the update Flag.

Comment: Thanks, I have that in place, and when I attempt to add the needsupdate I get an undefined error. I have just updated my post. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89949/discussion-between-falk-thiele-and-kode).